# How do I calculate whether a date is below a series of cutoffs quickly in R?

Tags: r

Say I have a series of dates, and I want to break them into groups (let's call the groups "epochs").  My first idea of how to do this would be to create a variable that indicates which epoch a date belongs in.  The following code shows what I want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(mosaic)
library(magrittr)

# Generate 1,000,000 random dates
set.seed(919)
df <- data.frame(dates = runif(1e6, -100, 100) + as.Date("2015-12-18"))

# Set two arbitrary dates as cutoffs
e1 <- as.Date("2015-10-01")
e2 <- as.Date("2015-12-20")

# Add a variable that indicates what the lowest cutoff date was
system.time(df %<>% mutate(epoch = derivedFactor(epoch.1 = dates < e1, 
                                                 epoch.2 = dates < e2,
                                                 .method = "first", 
                                                 .default = "epoch.3")))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 341.86    0.16  344.70
```

But this is very slow -- about 5 minutes on my laptop.  I imagine there is a faster way to do this.  For example, my naive guess would be that you could sort the data by date, find the last row where `dates < e1`, and then mark all the preceding rows as a 1, etc.  But maybe someone on here knows a better or more elegant way to do this?

Comment: does `?findInterval` help ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben Bolker pointed out, you can use `findInterval` to do this:

```
df %<>% mutate(epoch = findInterval(df$dates, c(e1, e2)))
head(df, 10)
##         dates epoch
## 1  2016-03-15     2
## 2  2016-01-02     2
## 3  2016-01-30     2
## 4  2015-10-03     1
## 5  2015-09-17     0
## 6  2016-02-11     2
## 7  2015-12-05     1
## 8  2015-12-15     1
## 9  2016-03-11     2
## 10 2015-10-21     1
```

On my machine, this takes much less than 0.1 second.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overthinking this. I did it in base `R`, but presumably you could do this in `dplyr` too. Just order the data, and then set the factor levels you want in decreasing order.

Conceptually, you just set everything to the most recent epoch, 3. Then, you go through and find all the rows that are less than the epoch 2 cutoff, and then change those to 2. Then, repeat the same process with 1.

```
# Generate 1,000,000 random dates
set.seed(919)
test.data <- data.frame(row_id = 1:1000000,dates = runif(1e6, -100, 100) + as.Date("2015-12-18"))

# Set two arbitrary dates as cutoffs
e1 <- as.Date("2015-10-01")
e2 <- as.Date("2015-12-20")

test.data <- test.data[order(test.data$dates),]
test.data$epoch <- 3
test.data[test.data$dates < e2,"epoch"] <- 2
test.data[test.data$dates < e1,"epoch"] <- 1

table(test.data$epoch)
```

Comment: Yes, you were right that I was overthinking it.  I chose the other one as an answer because it was more concise, but this is a good solution too.  Thanks.